# AngularJS Use Input Value Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

How can I direct AngularJS to assimilate the `value` attribute into the model?  Any field that I give an `ng-model` attribute has its `value` immediately replaced with nothing, or whatever I define in the controller.  Here's some code:

```
<form action="" method="post" ng-controller="PageCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" value="Initial field value">
</form>
```

And the Javascript...

```
function PageCtrl($scope, Slug) {
    $scope.title = null;
}
```

I've tried not setting`$scope.title`, setting it to other things, but no matter what I do, the `value` is completely ignored.  What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the value attribute is ignored by angularjs in favor of ng-model. It'd better just to remove value from your input entirely to avoid confusion.

The angular way of setting the default value would be to set `$scope.title = 'Initial field value'` inside your controller, and that's the preferable way to structure things as far as possible. If that's not possible then you can use ng-init on the input to do the same thing too, e.g.

```
 <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" ng-init="title = 'Initial field value'">
```

Comment: In this case, I'm building a form with Rails.  How would you recommend getting that data to the controller for form population?

Comment: @Jonah I'm not sure what the problem is?  You can set the $scope.title="some default value" or you can set a placeholder attribute on the input.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  You should be able to use either $http or $resource to communicate with the service layer.

Comment: @shaunhusain I want to be able to dynamically populate the form without any Javascript.  Seems like this ought to be basic functionality :(

Comment: @Jonah it is basic functionality, but the way to do it is to make an http call with the `$http` service inside your controller. Your angular app should interact with your ruby backend via http calls, not by having rails dynamically return different views.

Comment: One of the main points of having angular over ember *was* the ability to apply it to parts of the system, instead of doing a `single page app` from scratch - so you could still render a new page with form from server including model data in values, and update model via $http with angular. Now it seems like you need to render dumb form and make additional request for default/existing object data. Besides that you loose the fall back to regular form `POST` action. So bad..